# Assert an object is a specific type

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Is it possible in JUnit to assert an object is an instance of a class? For various reasons I have an object in my test that I want to check the type of. Is it a type of Object1 or a type of Object2?

Currently I have:

```
assertTrue(myObject instanceof Object1);
assertTrue(myObject instanceof Object2);
```

This works but I was wondering if there is a more expressive way of doing this.

For example something like:

```
assertObjectIsClass(myObject, Object1);
```

I could do this:

```
assertEquals(Object1.class, myObject.getClass());
```

Is there a specific assert method that allows me to test a type of an object in a more elegant, fluid manner?

Comment: Are you aware that `assertTrue(myObject instanceof Object1);` and `assertEquals(myObject.class, Object1.getClass());` are actually different tests? The first accepts myObject being an instance of a subclass of `Object1`, the later doesn't.

Comment: as maba points out, consider using Hamcrest. This is more than just so that you have a better working test. Hamcrest also provides much better logging of the failure than standard `assertTrue`. `assertTrue` would just say `expected true got false`, Hamcrest would say `expected instanced of XYZ, got instance of ABC`

Answer (score 294, accepted):

You can use the `assertThat` method and the Matchers that comes with JUnit.

Take a look at [this link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/matchers.html) that describes a little bit about the JUnit Matchers.

Example:

```
public class BaseClass {
}

public class SubClass extends BaseClass {
}
```

Test:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.instanceOf;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

/**
 * @author maba, 2012-09-13
 */
public class InstanceOfTest {

    @Test
    public void testInstanceOf() {
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
        assertThat(subClass, instanceOf(BaseClass.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the link to the Matcher being used: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#instanceOf(java.lang.Class)

Comment: FYI, MatcherAssert.assertThat behaves better (provides better logging in the case of errors) than Assert.assertThat. I recommend using it instead. http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/MatcherAssert.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers/comments. All useful. I'll use assertThat now in my code

Comment: That's a trivial assertion and would be a compile error if not true in the example! Usually you want to go down the class hierarchy with `instanceof`:
`BaseClass subClass = new SubClass(); assertThat(subClass, isA(SubClass.class));`, but it doesn't compile because `SubClass` is not `? super BaseClass`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob I don't understand what you are trying to say here... Try to change the `instanceOf(BaseClass.class)` to `instanceOf(String.class)` and you'll see that it compile just fine but there will be an AssertionError thrown.

Comment: @maba, he's talking about isA for some reason, which captures the class, it accepts `Class<T>` instead of `Class<?>` (which is what instanceOf does). Since it captures the class, it would be a compile time error to do isA with a class incompatible to the instance. https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/39

Comment: `AssertThat` is now deprecated in newer jUnit

Comment: @Carmageddon Simply use the `assertThat` in Hamcrest which is not deprecated.

Answer (score 80):

Since `assertThat` which was the old answer is now deprecated, I am posting the correct solution:

`assertTrue(objectUnderTest instanceof TargetObject);`

Comment: if objectUnderTest is a subclass of TargetObject, this will still result into `true` right? And I think you want to test the actual type.

Comment: I feel this is NOT the correct answer. The original question was asking for something that specifically checks on the exact type of the object. This solutions does not that (as mentioned by @EircG above) and it has even been provided by the user originally asking the question, so definitely not the "correct" answer imo.

For the correct answer, please check the Franklin Yu answer.

Comment: Well, it has the downside which @EricG mentioned yes, about Franklin's answer - I just looked at it, and it didnt make sense to me so I just tested in my project with Junit5 - it is wrong!! there is no such syntax for instanceof , nor a method called InstanceOf! He is totally wrong. I stand by my answer still, and as evidenced, it was helpful to at least 30 people who upvoted it! (I assume you downvoted).

Comment: @kekko12 My answer doesn’t check the exact type either; it accepts subclass similar to this answer. I have updated my answer to address it; sorry that I didn’t notice this part in question. I think exact equality isn’t included in most assertion library because it isn’t frequently used.

Comment: @Carmageddon The answer from Franlin Yu does work fine *if* you use hamcrest assertion importing:
```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.instanceOf;
```
ss per his code samples.

I do admit though I overlooked at Franklin answer and in fact, these 2 answers are functionally equivalent, so I guess it is just a matter of preference in the end.

Answer (score 39):

### Solution for JUnit 5

The documentation says:

> However, JUnit Jupiter’s [`org.junit.jupiter.Assertions`](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html) class does not provide an [`assertThat()`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher)) method like the one found in JUnit 4’s [`org.junit.Assert`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Assert.html) class which accepts a Hamcrest [`Matcher`](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/hamcrest/Matcher.html). Instead, developers are encouraged to use the built-in support for matchers provided by third-party assertion libraries.

Example for [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/):

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.instanceOf;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class HamcrestAssertionDemo {

    @Test
    void assertWithHamcrestMatcher() {
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
        assertThat(subClass, instanceOf(BaseClass.class));
    }

}
```

Example for [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/):

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class AssertJDemo {

    @Test
    void assertWithAssertJ() {
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
        assertThat(subClass).isInstanceOf(BaseClass.class);
    }

}
```

Note that this assumes you want to test behaviors similar to `instanceof` (which accepts subclasses). If you want exact equal type, I don’t see a better way than asserting the two class to be equal like you mentioned in the question.

Comment: In a sense, the original `assertThat()` is deferred to Hamcrest, so that JUnit also works with third-party assertion libraries.

Comment: I just tested this answer, it is NOT correct and leads to multiple compilation errors: Illegal start of expression, illegal start of type, ';' expected... In other words, your second parameter to the assertThat matcher, CANNOT be "instanceof (BaseClass.class)"! In fact, you didnt even type that correctly, the syntax  you used is slightly different - "InstanceOf(" - as a function call! There is no such function actually...  was it even tested by anyone? It seems to have been manually typed without any tests

Comment: @Carmageddon I provided two answers, one for Hamcrest and the other for AssertJ. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: @Carmageddon I suspect that you are talking about the Hamcrest example and you miss-typed `instanceOf` as `instanceof` (mind the case). `instanceOf` is [a function](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.1/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#instanceOf-java.lang.Class-) while `instanceof` is [a Java keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2).

Comment: I referred to the Hamcrest one of course, and I tried both keyword AND as a function after I noticed thats how you wrote it - there is no such function...

Comment: @Carmageddon From my comment above I have already linked to the Javadoc of this function so it clearly exist. If your compiler cannot find the function then there is something wrong with your environment. For example, please check whether you have the class file or Jar file in classpath, and you are using the correct version. Or maybe you missed the import statements? What error you got?

Comment: Hm I assume that the recent downvote isn't casted by this user since it has been a few weeks. Would be more helpful if the downvoter I receive a comment about it.

Comment: use `assertThat(actualException, not(instanceOf(BaseClass.class))); ` for negative test.

Answer (score 10):

## Experimental Solution for JUnit 5.8

In JUnit 5.8, the **experimental** [`assertInstanceOf()`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertInstanceOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.Object)) method was added, so you don't need Hamcrest or AssertJ anymore. The solution is now as simple as:

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertInstanceOf;

import org.junit.Test;

public class InstanceOfTest {

    @Test
    public void testInstanceOf() {
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass();
        assertInstanceOf(BaseClass.class, subClass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Solution for JUnit  for Kotlin

What worked for me:

```
assert(obj is ClassName)
```

for exmaple

```
assert(obj is User)
```

NOTE: assert is coming from `AssertionsJVM.kt` file

Answer (score 6):

### Solution for JUnit 5 for Kotlin!

Example for [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/):

```
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class HamcrestAssertionDemo {

    @Test
    fun assertWithHamcrestMatcher() {
        val subClass = SubClass()
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(subClass, CoreMatchers.instanceOf<Any>(BaseClass::class.java))
    }

}
```

Example for [AssertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/):

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

class AssertJDemo {

    @Test
    fun assertWithAssertJ() {
        val subClass = SubClass()
        assertThat(subClass).isInstanceOf(BaseClass::class.java)
    }

}
```

Comment: use `  assertThat(actualException, not(instanceOf(BaseClass.class))); ` for negative test.