# Test method return specific object junit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5

I'm trying to create my first tests.
I have to prove that a method returns a ContextLambda type, I am using the assertSame function to test it, but my test fails, I do not know what assert to use to test this, with assertEquals also fails.
my test is something like that:

```
@Test
public void testCanCreateContextForLambda() {
    ContextFactory factory = new ContextFactory();

    LambdaContext context = factory.forLambda(
            new FakeRequest(),
            new FakeResponse(),
            new FakeLambda()
    );
    assertSame(LambdaContext.class, context);
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to assert. The fact that you could assign the value to a local variable of type LambdaContext is already a 100% guarantee that the type us what you expect.

Comment: Java is a statically typed language. There is no point in testing the return type of a method (unless we are talking about polymorphism).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `instanceof` and `assertTrue`:
Include assertTrue import:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

And then the actual test:

```
@Test
public void testCanCreateContextForLambda() {
    ContextFactory factory = new ContextFactory();

    LambdaContext context = factory.forLambda(
            new FakeRequest(),
            new FakeResponse(),
            new FakeLambda()
    );
    assertTrue(context instanceof LambdaContext);
}
```

This assertion will be trivial and will always be true as long as `context` is a class of type `LambdaContext` (use interface for example to make it non-trivial).

Comment: There's another way of doing it using `assertThat`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404650/assert-an-object-is-a-specific-type

Comment: The import for Junit5 is `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue`.

Comment: i use assertThat( Object, instanceOf( AnotherObject) );  
these dependencies belong to import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.instanceOf;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion with `assertSame` asserts that `LambdaContext.class == context`. This will never be true.

You could correct your assertion in several ways

- `context instanceof LambdaContext` will be trivial (always true)
- `context.getClass() == LambdaContext.class` will be almost trivial (probably always true)

These tests can be written using `assertSame` and `assertTrue` of the junit5 library (see other answers).

My best advice: Drop this test and write one that asserts non-trivial properties of `context`.