# Verify if the correct data type using serialization

Tags: java, junit

I have a POJO provided below,

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class OrderDto extends BaseDto {

    @JsonProperty( "products" )
    private final List<String> products;

    @JsonProperty( "basket_items" )
    private final List<BasketItemDto> basketItems;

    @JsonProperty( "timestamp" )
    @JsonDeserialize( using = JavaOffsetDateTimeDeserializer.class )
    @JsonSerialize( using = JavaOffsetDateTimeSerializer.class )
    private OffsetDateTime timestamp;

    @JsonProperty( "amount" )
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @JsonProperty( "shop_id" )
    private Integer shopId;

    ..........................

}
```

I would like to test if the `timestamp` field is the `OffsetDateTime` data type.

Is it possible and how do I write a test about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assert an object is a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404650/assert-an-object-is-a-specific-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to test if the timestamp field is the OffsetDateTime data type.

Sure. A bit of guessing here, but I think what you want / intend to do:

- write a unit test that shows that the annotations within your POJO/DTO work as expected ...
- when parsing some JSON string

Thus, the point here is:

- **you** look out for some example JSON data that you consider *valid*
- then you write a unit test that uses jackson to de-serialize that JSON string into an instance of your DTO class
- then you use one or more asserts to **check** the fields of that freshly created `OrderDTO`

To add a bit more background: keep in mind that your only defining a data-holder object here. Your DTO doesn't have any behavior that you could test. The only thing that is worth testing here:

- when you do `new()` in Java, and populate the fields of such a dto manually, and you serialize to JSON, you can check if the string looks as expected
- or, as said, the other way round: you can **hardcode** a JSON string, de-serialize it, and then verify/assert that the properties you would expect (based on your knowledge of the incoming JSON string) really show up in your dto.

Finally: in case you don't have a proper "input" JSON string, the dangerous, but valid alternative: first write that test case that serializes a known object into a JSON string. Then de-serialize that string, and ensure that the de-serialized dto matches the one you serialized.

Answer (score 0):

Where/when do you want to validate/test it? You can use bean validation to validate the fields of your pojo. You can write your own validator for that as well.
How to bean validation: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation
Example for custom bean validation with spring: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: Can you provide an answer with the respective code?

Comment: Not really, I'm on my phone. Here is a good example/tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Comment: I am not sure if this answer is really correct. The OP asks how to **test** the content of his dto, not how to **validate** it. There is quite a difference between those two. So, maybe @U2m: step back and clarify what you really want to do here. Validation ensures that user provided input is sanity checked ... testing is something really different here!